# YUI AutoComplete Example Problem

Tags: autocomplete, yui, widget

I was hunting for an implementations of YUI AutoComplete and I came across this script from the site [asklaila.com](http://www.asklaila.com) -

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    YAHOO.example.ACJson = new function() {
        this.oACDS = new YAHOO.widget.DS_XHR("/AutoComplete.do", 
            ["Suggestions[0].Results","Name"]);

        this.oACDS.queryMatchContains = true;
        this.oACDS.scriptQueryAppend = "city=Mysore"; // Needed for YWS
        function fnCallback(e, args) {
            document.searchForm.where.focus();
            acSelected = true;
            return false;
        }

        this.oAutoComp = new YAHOO.widget.AutoComplete('what','whatContainer', this.oACDS);
        this.oAutoComp.itemSelectEvent.subscribe(fnCallback);
        this.oAutoComp.formatResult = function (oResultItem,sQuery) {
            return oResultItem[0];
        }

        this.oAutoComp.queryDelay = 0;
        this.oAutoComp.useIFrame = true; 
        this.oAutoComp.prehighlightClassName = "yui-ac-prehighlight";
        this.oAutoComp.minQueryLength = 2;
        this.oAutoComp.autoHighlight = false;
        this.oAutoComp.textboxFocusEvent.subscribe(function() {
            this.oAutoComp.sendQuery("");
        });

        this.oAutoComp.doBeforeExpandContainer = function(oTextbox, oContainer, sQuery, aResults) {
            var pos = YAHOO.util.Dom.getXY(oTextbox);
            pos[1] += YAHOO.util.Dom.get(oTextbox).offsetHeight + 2;
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setXY(oContainer,pos);
            return true;
        };
    }
</script>
```

It is implenting the YUI AutoComplete Dropdown. What I want to understand is what this

```
this.oACDS = new YAHOO.widget.DS_XHR("/AutoComplete.do", ["Suggestions[0].Results","Name"]);
```

does and its effects on code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.oACDS = new YAHOO.widget.DS_XHR("/AutoComplete.do", ["Suggestions[0].Results","Name"]);

On every key press, it fetches a json response from the server, and uses it to populate the autocomplete dropdown. The json contains names to display only at this node, "Suggestions[0].Results" in the "name" field.

If you have any trouble, ask ahead. I wrote that piece of code for asklaila.com

Comment: hi anuj! thanks for the help. 've sent you a mail on anuj[@+]anujrathi[d0+]com..pls have a look.

Answer (score 1):

That's using an older version of YUI, but it is setting up a DataSource for the autocomplete to read from. This particular DataSource uses XHR to request information from the server to populate the autocomplete field.

```
"Autocomplete.do"
```

Is a relative URL that is being queried by the DataSource every time the autocomplete fires while the user is typing.

```
["Suggestions[0].Results","Name"]
```

Is the responseSchema that tells the DataSource how to parse the results from the request to the URL. It needs to know how to parse the data so that it can show the proper results.

Comment: so this autocomplete.do resides on the host's site itself right? also. So the name of the schema is "Suggestions[0].Results" and the field to query is "Name" correct?

Comment: Yes. I really recommend you look at the examples on the YUI site instead of trying to use some random in-the-wild version. The examples are fantastic & should be really useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I was hunting for implementations of
>   YUI Autocomplete and I came across
>   this script...

Why not take a look at YUI AutoComplete page for in-depth examples.

[Yahoo! UI Library: AutoComplete](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/)

Comment: i did see that, and made an implementation of my own. I was wondering how does that one work on the link i posted, or at least to understand which method is that is it using.

Do you have any idea or exp in using YUI? Can you help me clear some doubts?